# borders of a dropdown not wrapping around my header

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a dropdown menu that contains a list of articles with the pictures of the authors next to it. Originally, I was going to use Bootstrap 4's "card" system, but the pictures on cards could only be on top or bottom so I went with the regular div element inside a dropdown list. However, the dropdown menu default CSS through Bootstrap isn't wrapping around the length of my fictional article titles as it should.

See pic below.

[image]

The header element is inside the dropdown-menu div so I'm not sure what's going on. There's no real CSS aside from hover color changes outside the default Bootstrap 4 CSS. Oh, I put a solid border around the entire menu row just so I could see it. Eventually I'll remove it.

Here is my html.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" style="border: 1px solid;">
                <div class="btn-group" id="newsbtn">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"> Latest News & articles</i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                          <a class="dropdown-item item-list" href="#">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 no-padding photobox">
                                    <div class="add-image">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail no-margin" src="1.jpg"
                                             alt="img">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h6>The most popular 80s pedals on Reverb</h6>
                                    <span class="row pl-3">Johnna B. Goode</span>
                                    <span class="info-row text-muted">
                                        <span class="date">
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <small> Today 9:20 am</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 no-padding photobox">
                                    <div class="add-image">
                                        <img class="img-thumbnail no-margin" src="10.jpg"
                                             alt="img">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <p>Gibson vs. Epiphone: The Sound Matters</p>
                                    <span class="row pl-3">Damon Wayne</span>
                                    <span class="info-row text-muted">
                                        <span class="date">
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                                            <small> Yesterday</small>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Article 3</a>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-block" id="viewallbtn">View all articles</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you have the code posted somewhere so that we can inspect it?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. If I put it in a jFiddle it doesn't come out right unless I try to grab all the default Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: You need to make a demo of the issue on codepen,jsfiddle etc.

Comment: On jsfiddle on the left, click resources and you can link bootstrap so it will come out correctly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JSable/unkn34kd/

Comment: For some reason on the jFiddle, my dropdowns don't even show up but on my regular website they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to `apply display:inline-block;` to all the inner elements of your drop-down.

You should really consider using a separate CSS file, it's a lot easier to handle.

The css should contain this:

```css
.dropdown-menu div
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

This will apply to every div inside the dropdown-menu.

If your elements inside the dropdown does unexpected stuff, you can use this to make every element stay on it's same line:

```css
.dropdown-menu div {
   clear:both;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Chrisimir - that isn't working. I have my own CSS file, but I haven't used it to change any of the default CSS from bootstrap pertaining to dropdowns.

Comment: @J.G.Sable Have you tried putting the styles inside the html tags? `<div class="dropdown-menu" style="display:inline-block;">` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this css,

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Worked on the first article. Second article title is still overflowing.

Comment: I edited my css with removing `.item-list` class. Please apply and let me know

Comment: When I removed that, it actually overflows again.

Comment: then use `white-space: normal !important;`